# f continuous and differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

Consider the function $$f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}\; (x,y)\mapsto \begin{cases}
  \frac{x^ay^b}{(x^2+y^2)^c},  & (x,y)\not=(0,0)\text{,}\\
  0, & \text{else }
\end{cases}$$
I am trying to proof

a)f is continuous in $(0,0)\iff a+b\ge 2c+1$

b)f is differentiable in $(0,0)\iff a+b\ge 2c+2$

My try:

What I tried:  $\lim\limits_{r\to 0}f(rcos\varphi,rsin\varphi)=\lim\limits_{r\to 0}\frac{(rcos\varphi)^a(rsin\varphi)^b}{(r^2)^c}=\lim\limits_{r\to 0}r^{a+b-2c}cos^a\varphi sin^b\varphi=0$ $\iff$ $a+b-2c\ge 1$.

I'm not sure if the last step is ok. Or shall I seperate both directions in the proof?

b) $\lim\limits_{t\to 0}\frac{f((0,0)+tv)-f((0,0)}{t}=\lim\limits_{t\to 0}\frac{f(tv_1,tv_2)}{t}=\lim\limits_{t\to 0}\frac{t^{a+b}v_1^av_2^b}{t^{2c-1}(v_1^2+v_2^2)^c}=0$ $\iff$ $a+b-2c-1\ge 1$.  Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

Your first part looks great. You don't need to add any more steps, but you should say something about how cosine and sine are continuous and bounded, so they don't affect the convergence behavior around 0. Both directions seem clear to me.

For your second part, how are you defining differentiability? You have only checked verified that the directional derivative exists for each $v$. You have to do a little more work to prove that $f$ is fully differentiable at $(0,0)$. I would try it with an sequence of vectors of the form $t_n u_n$ where $t_n \to 0$ and $|u_n|=1$. It will looks very similar to what you've done. You have the right idea for evaluating the limit.

There is also a typo in the last limit. It should read $t^{2c+1}$.